# How can I really remove an eSIM card from my iPhone 12 mini?

Tags: iphone, ios, esim

I have an iPhone 12 mini running iOS 15. It uses an eSIM card. I would like to use that eSIM card on another phone.

On the iPhone 12, I sent to Settings -> Cellular -> Remove Cellular Plan.

However, when I added the eSIM card via the QR code on the other phone, I get the error message:

[image]

It sounds like the eSIM card was not 100% removed from my iPhone 12 mini.
How can I really remove an eSIM card from my iPhone 12 mini?

Comment: Which mobile provider are you using? Some providers require the IMEI to be associated with the phone manually via their website/tech support, and won't update it properly automatically. My provider seemed to fall into this boat for physical SIMs, and even though things would mostly work after just moving the SIM around, I'd get weird behavior occasionally unless I updated on the website.

Comment: @JMY1000 Thanks, I don't think it's a provider issue, since removing the eSIM card worked fine on the other phone (I had first removed the eSIM card, then add it in the iPhone 12. But now it's "stuck" on that iPhone 12. The other phone is a  Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra)

Comment: I'd be inclined to agree, but I had *weird* behavior if I didn't update the IMEI; it wasn't that it consistently wouldn't work. If your provider offers/requires it, it's worth a shot.